# Bit wise operation on float value on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcommand

I would like to perform a simple update with bit switching on SQL with following code.

`UPDATE table SET BoolFields = BoolFields + 1.0 WHERE BoolFields & 1.0 <> 1.0`

However, when I run this on Management Studio, I receive

> Operand data type float is invalid for '&' operator.

Would anybody have clue to fix this issue without changing the BooFields from float to some other type?

EDIT

Some are commenting my condition was not clear so editing.

The condition is that I want to check and see if certain bit is flagged as one.
So my actual line could be `BoolFields & 128.0 <> 128.0`

then

I would like to `SET BoolFields = BoolFields + 128.0`

so I just would like to flag a boolean value ONLY when it is not flagged as 1.

Comment: it would help if you can tell on what conditions should the `update` execute? it is unclear from the question.

Comment: Please explain, what you want to achieve. This smells like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Bitwise on a ***float***? Why are you using float *at all*, but especially when storing bits?

Comment: After reading through the code, the code interpreter does store them as just plain integer. It seems to be recognized as float by SSMS though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use **bitwise** operator on your **float values - which do not support them** - you need to cast them to the type supporting bitwise operations like `bit` or `int` (listed here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx), i.e:

```
update table set BoolFields = BoolFields + 1.0 where cast(BoolFields as int) & 1 <> 1
```

But in my opinion, you should consider operating on ranges of float numbers instead of forcing bitwise operators. Maybe you should describe a use case in order to shed some light, why you want to do this.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Our code does use more than 16 bits so we do need 32 bits storages, but I wish we used bigint instead of float for storing a bit information. But I do not have authority to change the type.

Comment: Well int has 32 bits not 16. So I truely do not know why we are using float but we are. And as stated above, I cannot change the type...